# WSo2 EI - JSON Output from API to Database (External)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

New to WSO2 EI,

I have built an API that will give a response JSON, i want to parse and save this in Database. How can I do this. 
Db is external Oracle, for which I have a JNDI built already.

~Jawa

Comment: Does the API need to do the storing in the database before it is sent, or do you need to store a response after receiving it?

Comment: Need to parse the API output JSON and store it in Db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this,either you can perform entire things in ESB or you can use DSS as well.

Once you get JSON response you need to frame a query, you can use DB mediator add insert query which would then insert into DB.

Else you can create a data service in DSS and then pass this JSON, write a insert query in DSS and insert it into DB.

For DB mediator check this link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/DB+Report+Mediator

For Data service check below link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS322/Exposing+Data+as+REST+Resources

Comment: Any idea how to map my JSON value to a database column  (Manual SQL Statement)

Comment: If you are using DB mediator then below query you can use. <statement>
                    <sql>insert into company set price=? where name =?</sql>
                    <parameter expression="<JSON Expression>"
                               xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd" type="DOUBLE"/>
                    <parameter expression="JSON_Expression"
                             xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd" type="VARCHAR"/>
                </statement>